# two-dimensional array inside two-dimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

Is it possible to achieve something like this? A two-dimensional array containing two-dimensional jagged array?

```
$jobOrder = array(array(1, "Web Developer", 100, 
                        array(array(1, "PHP", 1),
                              array(2, "HTML", 1), array(3, "JAVA", 1)),
                        array(array(1, "pleasing personality", 1), 
                              array(2, "english skills", 1)), 0), 
                 array(2, "Senior Programmer", 50, 
                       array(array(3, "Phython", 1), 
                             array(5, "RUBY", 1), 
                             array(10, "c#", 1)), 
                       array(array(5, "good social skills", 1), 
                             array(11, "management skills", 1))));
```

I want to store Job Order details into an array that should contain an orderID, job title, number of openings, skills(may have multiple skills so stored in an array; 2-d because I also wanted to store skillID, skill name and flag: if its been removed or not), qualifications(may have multiple qualifications same with skills), requirements and benefits (also same with skills). I would like to know how to access it.

Comment: yes, arrays can be infinitely nested.

Comment: yes it's possible in the same way. you just add more `[#]` at the end for each level you go down. but a tip you run into the possibility of having to duplicate lines of code and make it harder to maintain. assume you have multiple roles that use *"JAVA"* and later you discover that you need to change that to *"JavaScript"*. sure you can do a find and replace but what if you make a spelling mistake? an idea is to create a separate array for say your Programming Languages then do something like `array(1, "Web Developer",100,array($progSkills[3]))`

Comment: Thank you for answering. I would also like to express my gratitude in giving me some tips, I will surely keep that on mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access element like this:

```
$jobOrder = array(array(1, "Web Developer", 100, 
                        array(array(1, "PHP", 1),
                              array(2, "HTML", 1), array(3, "JAVA", 1)),
                        array(array(1, "pleasing personality", 1), 
                              array(2, "english skills", 1)), 0), 
                 array(2, "Senior Programmer", 50, 
                       array(array(3, "Phython", 1), 
                             array(5, "RUBY", 1), 
                             array(10, "c#", 1)), 
                       array(array(5, "good social skills", 1), 
                             array(11, "management skills", 1))));

 print_r($jobOrder[0][3]);
```

I will print the array and also you can access the elements in the array also by adding further indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible as you can store number of array rows in the array: means you can add number of rows as well number of elements inside the array even it may multidimensional array as you defined.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I would also like to know how should I access those inner 2-d arrays.

Comment: @ArleneMariano `echo $jobOrder[0][3][0][1];` //=php